# no javascript intellisense in a particular web application (VS2015)

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

In one of my solutions, I have a class library project and two web applications. In the web applications, on the .cshtml pages, I have Razor intellisense, but absolutely nothing for Javascript. If I type "$." and hit ctrl+space, nothing happens. no popups. This is very frustrating because I am not all that familiar with JS! HOWEVER, in a different solution with a web app, I *do* have javascript intellisense. This makes me think it is not Visual Studio that is broken. It's something about this particular solution. This makes this question unique among the other similar StackOverflow questions.

I have tried every answer I can find on StackOverflow. Especially everyone's favorite,  adding the /Scripts/_reference.js file to the Tools | Options | Code Editor | Javascript | Intellisense setting. That does not help. I have tried downgrading jQuery from 3.1.1 to 2.x, the same version used in the solution that works. I have tried editing the _reference.js file to have fewer items. I have disabled Resharper. I have unloaded and reloaded the project. I have restarted VS. I have not reset the settings of VS because that would be too chaotic, and since it works in other projects, i don't want to.

What I need is someone who understands how Visual Studio determines how to display intellisense to give me a checklist of things that need to be in place for it to work. The key clue here is why would one solution work properly but another doesn't? What sort of project level setting could affect this?

Here is my /Scripts/_references.js file:

```
/// <autosync enabled="false" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.intellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" />
/// <reference path="bloodhound.js" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.countdown.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.js" />
/// <reference path="typeahead.bundle.js" />
/// <reference path="typeahead.jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="typeahead.mvc.model.js" />
```

Comment: Have you tried add a new .cshtml page? Both of this two web application project have this issue with a new .cshtml file? Back up this solution then remove the class library project and web application one by one, to check if the other project effects this issue. Delete the .suo or .vs file under your solution folder, the .vs folder might be hidden, restart VS and reopen this solution to check this issue again. Meanwile, I found in your _references.js file, ‘autosync’ is ‘false’, the default value is ‘true’, you can also modify it and clean up the solution, rebuild it and test.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can right click the .cshtml file an choose ‘Open with…’ and it should be ‘HTML Editor (Default)’. Try to open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the commands: devenv /resetuserdata to clean up the old user data. Or delete or rename the folders: C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sara-msft helped me to troubleshoot this on the visual studio forums, and i'll repost the information here to help others. First, she gave me some great steps to try:

> Refer to your description, this issue only happens in this solution.
>   We need to check if this issue existing for all .cshtml files among
>   this solution or not, please have a look at the following to
>   troubleshot: (Back up the solution before any modification, in case we
>   need to roll back. )
>
> 1. Add a new .cshtml file under the same web page or another web page project to test the intellisense
> 2. Add a new web application, then add a new .cshtml file under this new web application and check
> 3. Remove the class library project and web application project one by one to check if the other project affects this issue
>
> Meanwhile, you can try the following methods which usually work for
>   the intellisense not working issue:
>
> 1. Delete the .suo or .vs file under your solution folder, the .vs folder might be hidden, restart VS and reopen this solution to check
>      this issue again.
> 2. In your _references.js file, ‘autosync’ is ‘false’, the default value is ‘true’, you can also modify it and clean up the solution,
>      rebuild it, then test the intellisense again
> 3. Right click the .cshtml file an choose ‘Open with…’ and it should be ‘HTML Editor (Default)’.
> 4. Try to open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run the
>      commands: devenv /resetuserdata to clean up the old user data. 5.
>      Delete or rename the folders: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 to clean up
>      the cache data.

I had success at step 2.

***2. Add a new web application, then add a new .cshtml file under this new web application and check***

I took this to mean add a new application to the broken solution, so I did that. JS Intellisense works in this new project! This was a great thing to try. It began with JQuery 1.x and I upgraded to 3.1.1 to match the other projects. This weakened the quality of the intellisense, giving only a minimal amount of information. I took a peek in _references.js and noticed that only the jquery.min.* and jquery.slim.* files existed. I removed those references and changed it to the jquery-3.1.1.js file. So my ~/Scripts/_references.js looks like this:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.js" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.6.2.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.js" />
```

This greatly improved the quality of the JS intellisense, because it's not using the minified versions, and it is reading from the jquery-3.1.1.intellisense.js file as well.

BUT! What about my other projects? I copied the above _references.js code and pasted that into the _references.js in the broken projects. It works! Yay! But why?

I started removing individual lines from the broken _references.js file. It didn't take me long to find the culprit.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" />
```

This reference broke all my javascript intellisense. Removing it fixed my problem. Thank you Sara for your help troubleshooting this!

UPDATE: I should add that the offending reference wasn't the only one that would break intellisense. I have found others as well, notably KendoUI. So if you have this problem, start removing references in _references.js until javascript works again.

Comment: Hi redwards, you can mark your reply as answer when you have free time, it is just a reminder :)